# How do i use the replaceAll function to mask numbers? (Java GUI)

Tags: java, swing

Trying to mask the numbers with '*' generated by a random number generator, how do I go about doing this? AFAIK I have to use the replaceAll function?

```
btnGenerate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) { 
                    int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
                    tfNum.setText(rand + "");
                }
            }   
        });
```

Comment: So, you're trying to generate a random number of stars?

Comment: Nope, so for example the random number generator generates 94 i want to mask this value such that when i run the programme it displays '**'

Comment: ...which is a randomly-generated number of stars, no?

Comment: @AndyTurner I think he wants to generate a random number, then hide the number using stars. You *could* say it's generating a random amount of stars, that is true in a sense since the number is random. But it's a battle not worth engaging.

Comment: @ztw So if you generate 1, you want to display "*" and if you generate 123, you want to display "***"? Your verbal explanation of the problem is not clear so update your question to give us an example of a) the number that is generated and b) what is displayed in the text field. Also the code you posted makes no sense. You have a loop. So if you generate 20 random numbers, how to you expect them to display in the text field? The setText(…) replaces the old text, so all you will ever see is the last number generated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regular expression `[0-9]` to select all numbers in your replaceAll method.

I couldn't really tell  the context of your code but here's an example:

```
String nums = "1212";
nums = nums.replaceAll("[0-9]", "*");
System.out.println(nums);
```

Result:

```
****
```

Comment: Tried this but my numbers aren't replaced with stars any idea why? Converted my random number from an int to String before using replaceAll.                `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) { 
              int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
              String inString=Integer.toString(rand);
              inString.replaceAll("[0-9]", "*");
              tfNum.setText(inString);
       }`

Comment: Strings are immutable so you have to assign the return value of replaceAll back to inString

`inString = inString.replaceAll("[0-9]", "*");`

Comment: Or `Integer.toString(rand).replaceAll(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll` is overkill for this. There's no need to fire up the whole regular expression machinery (which would re-compile the regex on each execution) for something you can achieve with simple arithmetic and a `StringBuilder`.

Since you're generating a number, you're merely generating a random number of stars. The only thing in the unmasked string that's not a digit would be a negative sign.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (rand < 0) sb.append('-');
do {
  sb.append('*');
  rand /= 10;
} while (rand != 0);  // Use do/while in order to generate '*' when rand is zero initially.
String randStr = sb.toString();
```

But depending on the range of numbers you can possibly generate, it may be easier just to have an if/else with a small handful of hard-coded strings:

```
if (rand >= 0 && rand < 10) randStr = "*";
else if (rand >= 10 && rand < 100) randStr = "**";
else if (rand >= 100 && rand < 1000) randStr = "***";
else throw new AssertionError();
```

Comment: Okay will give this a go too! Thanks!